# Class has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Environment (class file version 52.0.)'

Tags: java, mulesoft, anypoint-studio

Hi I am doing a course on Mulesoft and one of the exercises I need to locally host a database to help do the course exercises
The first step is to run a jar file

When I try to run the command java -jar mulesoft-training-services-1.8.8.jar, I am getting a compiler error which says 'Class has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Environment (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0.'

Now from reading, I know this is to do with jre and it seems I only have jre8 whereas this is Jre11. How would I go about fixing this? Do I need to update the JRE? If so how do I do it? Or is it my path and execution variables which need to be set?

If this is not the answer, is there something I can change in anypoint studio (which is the mulesoft IDE very similar to eclipse) to fix this?

Sorry I am new to this so if anything doesn't make sense, please let me know

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to update your JRE.

How you do it depends on what OS you use and how previous JRE was installed.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. The jar file was compiled using Java 11 so you need to have a Java 11 JRE or OpenJDK 11 to be able to execute it

Answer (score 0):

You can not do something here with Anypoint Studio.

Answers to your questions as below

1. **Do I need to update the JRE?** - Yes, you have to update with Java 11 JRE or OpenJDK 11.
2. **If so, how do I do it?** - you can download it from this link https://adoptopenjdk.net/
3. **is it my path and execution variables that need to be set?** - yes, you need to set the environment variable into your machine to point it to the correct installation directories for JRE.